# Puppet exec not executed

Tags: linux, puppet, tar

```
exec { "Installing application by extracting archive file ${app_package_archive} in ${install_dir}":
    cwd => "${install_dir}",
    path => ['/usr/bin','/bin','/usr/sbin','/sbin'],
    command => "tar xf ${app_package_archive}",
    user => 'root',
    creates => "${install_dir}/${app_package_dir}",
    require => File["${install_dir}/${app_package_archive}"],
    logoutput => true
}
```

I have this puppet code block. This code block is extracting the application package tar file. I want that every time I have a new application package when extracting puppet will overwrite the existing application folder. This code block works fine if there is no old application folder. But if there is it is not even executed. Any help will be much appreciate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [documentation for `exec`](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/type.html#exec).  You are using the [`creates`](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/type.html#exec-attribute-creates) keyword:

> A file to look for before running the command. The command will only run if the file doesn’t exist.

If you want your `exec` resource to run every time, just remove `creates` from the resource definition.